# Javascript replace関数について

Tags: javascript, html

scriptにreplace関数を用いたのですが
型が一致してないのか、
うまく機能しません。色々なサイトを見ても
型に注意した扱い方がわからないため
誤用してる点をご指摘ください。
参考サイトURL載せてくださると助かります。

```html
<html>

<head>
  </head>

<body>
  <br />
  <form name="js">
    <input name="a" type="text" />x+<input name="b" type="text" />y=<input name="c" type="text" />
    <br />
    <input onclick="calculate()" type="button" value="計算する" />
    <br />
    <input onclick="clr()" type="button" value="消去" /><br />
  </form>
  <span id="a"></span>x+<span id="b"></span>y=<span id="c">
　　　　</span>
  <script>
    function calculate() {　　　
      var d = new Array(4);　　　　
      var stringa;　　　
      d[0] = document.js.a.value;　　　　
      stringa = d[0].replace(/&/g, '&amp');　　　　
      document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = stringa;
    }
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: 「うまく機能しません」とのことですが、具体的に説明してください。

Answer (score 3):

質問者さんは「うまく機能しません」とのことでしたが、Internet ExplorerやGoogle Chrome上で機能しているように見えます。

> ```
> stringa = d[0].replace(/&/g, '&amp');
> ```

`&amp`ではなく正しくは`&amp;`のはずです。[文字実体参照](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%8F%82%E7%85%A7)

Comment: Google chromeで機能させたいのですが方法はありますか。

Comment: document.<name> は挙動がHTML規格で定義されています。https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-nameditem Google Chrome でも動きます。

Comment: @int32_t さん、その機能が仕様書に記載されていることは知りませんでした。ただMDNに記載がないようですがどう解釈すればいいのでしょう？ また質問者さんはChromeで動かないとのことですが、では原因はなんでしょう？

Comment: MDNの記載漏れでしょう。質問のコードは、&amp の件をのぞけば Google Chrome でも書かれている通りに動いているように見えます。

Comment: 質問者さんの反応を待っていましたが反応がないので、誤っている記述を削除しました。 @int32_t さん指摘ありがとうございます。